# How to check if an image in completely uploaded or not in PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload, imagemagick, php-gd

Here's the scenario. I have two requests, one to upload the image, and another to process the uploaded image. 
Doing a `file_exists()` check allows me to know if the file exists or not.
But the problem arises when I hit the second request(to process the image) before even the file is completely uploaded. *Correct me if I am wrong*, the `file_exists()` returns `true` because even when one single byte is uploaded, the file gets created, even though the image data is not completely uploaded, and this gives issues when we further process the image.

One of the solution is a client side checksum, that i validate to know if the file is uploaded or not.

I would like to know if this check can be done in PHP alone?

I have tried using PHP [`Imagick`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) like

```
try {
    $imageMagickCheck = new Imagick($filename);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    $error = $exc->getMessage();
    file_put_contents("/tmp/corruption.log", $error."\n",FILE_APPEND);
    $imageMagickCheck = FALSE;
}
```

The above code gives an exception, if I manually remove the binary data of an image via. a text editor and then feed that file into the code. So, I thought it should recognize if an image is completely uploaded or not. But, I didn't see any exceptions in doing so. I am not sure why. I read somewhere that we can do something similar with [`createimagefromjpg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php).

Would really appreciate if someone good give me a clear picture regarding this.

**Image upload procedure**

Image upload happens in two stages. Basically the image processing server is a [`Lua-Openresty`](http://openresty.org/en/) server, and we have a wrapper for that written in PHP.
The client uploads the image as a Multipart form upload, which i receive in the `$_FILES` array in the PHP wrapper. I then upload this file to the Lua server using `cURL`. Lua again saves this file into its respective directory. Both the PHP Wrapper and the openresty server share the same file system. It makes sense to not send the file to lua, and save the file via PHP itself(which I am planning to do), but, even then, the problem still remains.

Comment: How do you upload the file?

Comment: Usually, an upload will give you also the size of the uploaded file. You could check against filesize for an extra check.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Now that u mention, I should include it in the question. There are two phases of the upload, the first is a basic multipart form upload that i receive in `$_FILES` array. The next phase is uploading the file to a Lua server, using PHP Curl. I'll include this in detail in the question.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Please check my update.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog why are you doing it in 2 steps? You can use the PHP curl library to post the image to your Lua server. Just need to add the curl code at the end of upload function.

Comment: @vishwakarma09 This is because I don't want to expose the URL of the Image processing server that the Clients will use. For that, I am using a PHP wrapper (our API) which acts as a middleware to do other validations(which includes checking if the file is completely uploaded of not) before passing the processing onto the Image processor.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog In no way that will be shown to clients. That is written in PHP server side. Let's assume your upload will go to upload function. In that function after you are done with file move/rename/etc,. you just run the curl code (your PHP wrapper)

Comment: @vishwakarma09 That's what is happening. Please read the question again. to curl it from PHP, u have to first upload the file to PHP right? That makes it two staged. I don't really understand what you are trying to say and how this will help in checking if the file is 100% uploaded or not.

Answer (score -1):

use is_uploaded_file();

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: `is_uploaded_file()` Returns TRUE if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST. This wont help to check if the uploaded file is 100% uploaded or not.

Answer (score -1):

In such case you can try this one

```
 public function checkcompletefileuploaded($url = '') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // don’t download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if (curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $result = checkcompletefileuploaded($imagefullpath);

  if($result){
    echo "File upoloaded succesfully";
  }else{
    echo "File not uploaded";
  }
```

Note: $imagefullpath: file path of newly uploaded(destination folder path).